# Why can an array encompass elements of strings?

Tags: c, translation, declaration, string-concatenation, string-literals

I don't comprehend why double quotes are included in the following array; isn't this of string type?

```c
const uint8_t u8x8_font_8x13_1x2_n[436] U8X8_FONT_SECTION("u8x8_font_8x13_1x2_n") = 
  " :\1\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\0\0@P\340\340P@\0\0\0\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\300\0\0\0\0\0\1\1\7"
  "\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \30\30\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\1\1"
  "\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\70\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200@\60\0\30\4\2\1"
  "\0\0\0\0\0\300 \20\20 \300\0\0\7\10\20\20\10\7\0\0@ \360\0\0\0\0\0\20\20\37"
  "\20\20\0\0\0`\20\20\20\20\340\0\0\30\24\22\22\21\20\0\0\20\20\20\220P\60\0\0\10\20\21"
  "\21\21\16\0\0\0\200@ \360\0\0\0\7\4\4\4\37\4\0\0\360\20\220\220\220\20\0\0\11\21\20"
  "\20\20\17\0\0\300 \20\20\20\0\0\0\17\22\21\21\21\16\0\0\20\20\20\220P\60\0\0\0\30\6"
  "\1\0\0\0\0\340\20\20\20\20\340\0\0\16\21\21\21\21\16\0\0\340\20\20\20\220\340\0\0\0\21\21"
  "\21\10\7\0\0\0\200\300\200\0\0\0\0\0\20\71\20\0\0";
```

The following example represents my commonly used declaration format for arrays.

```c
int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

Comment: What is `U8X8_FONT_SECTION`?

Comment: This ought to be a macro definition; the following code is associated with it.
`#ifndef U8X8_FONT_SECTION
#  define U8X8_FONT_SECTION(name) `

Comment: In C you can break strings in more parts simply closing and reopening with a double quote. In your case you have a **single string** which include escaped numbers, mostly decimal, and standard characters (many '@'). Because your array data is defined as in string format, it also includes the null terminating character zero.

Comment: A string literal is just a more convenient form of defining an array of `char`. Instead of `"hello"` you can also write `{'h','e','l','l','o',0}` to initialize an array. With that in mind, that's not too different from what you use for your `int` array.

Comment: Is your main concern about using a string literal to initialize a `uint8_t` array or is it about having multipe lines with strings?

Comment: `multipe lines with strings`,Because it differs from the array definition I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C Standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases)

> 1 The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by
> the following phases.
>
> //...
>
> 6. **Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated**.

So for example this declaration

```
char s[] = "Hello World!";
```

is equivalent to

```
char s[] = "Hello " 
           "World!";
```

Such splitting of a big string literal into several adjacent string literals makes code more readable.